# sql query or javascript code to count number of months in database and multiply that with total value in laravel

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, laravel

I struck at a small login, not able to crack. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a database as below.

```
  username    startdate   enddate     timedifference 
      user1   12-07-2017   13-07-2017  24
      user2  12-06-2017   13-06-2017   24
      user1   11-05-2016   12-05-2016  24
      user2   13-03-2016   15-03-2016  48
      user3   9-02-2015   10-02-2015   24
      user1   11-09-2017  12-09-2017   24
      user1   10-08-2017  11-08-2017   24
```

since 3 months entries in year 2017
Expected output for year 2017 for user1 = ((24+24+24)/(3*24*30))*100 = 3.33%

now I want to find

```
   value = (totaltimedifference)/(number of months data in database * 24*30) *100
```

Basically I want to find the percentage.

My code so far is

```
$percentageutilizationtesting = graphdata::select(DB::raw("
            (SUM(month(start))*(count(month(start)* 24*30)*100) as month, SUM(difference) as data, userid as username, year(start) as year"))     
                             ->groupBy(DB::raw("month(start)"))
                             ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(start)"))
                             ->groupBy('userid')
                             ->get()
                             ->toArray();
```

I tried count(month(start)) but it is counting the total number of entries in that month whereas I want to multiply only the number of months in that year.

I am not able to find the number of months, and I don't know the correct query to execute or if it is not possible in laravel please help me with javascript code.

Your help would very appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't `start` be `startdate`, and `difference` be `timedifference`?

Comment: both are correct for your understanding i have given it as startdate. it is actually start only.

Comment: What is the datatype of `timedifference`?

Comment: Could you show an example of what the result should be?

Comment: its datatype is varchar

Comment: `count(month(start)* 24*30)` doesn't make much sense. `count()` just counts the number of non-null values it receives, there's no reason to perform calculations in there.

Comment: So how do you expect to add strings that are like `24hr`? What do you expect `totaldifference` to be with values like that?

Comment: for example if user1 has 1 month data in 2017 and 1 month data in 2016 so for the year  2016  it will be like = (240/1*24*30)*100 = 33.33%

Comment: Edit the question and show the results as a table. The results should be for the sample input data you showed.

Comment: I have edited the question please check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Laravel syntax, but the MySQL query should be:

```
SELECT username, YEAR(startdate) AS year, SUM(timedifference)/(COUNT(DISTINCT(MONTH(startdate)))*24*30)*100 AS average
FROM graphdata
GROUP BY username, year
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdddfe/3)

`COUNT(DISTINCT(MONTH(startdate)))` counts the number of different months in the year for the user.

Comment: Thanks, let me try.

Comment: it is giving some wrong result. i think it is count all the records and multiplying with 24*30 but it should actually take the number of months in that year ie 2*24*30.

Comment: It's giving the answer you said, 2017 user1 is 3.3333. Which result is wrong?

Comment: I asked you to post the results as a table, but you just gave one example.

Comment: Maybe `COUNT(*)` should be `COUNT(DISTINCT(MONTH(startdate)))`

Comment: I'm getting the same results with my change. All the users in your example have only one row per month, so `COUNT(*)` is the same as `COUNT(DISTINCT(MONTH(startdate)))`

Comment: Thanks let me cross check.

Comment: Thanks Barmar its working perfect with COUNT(DISTINCT(MONTH(startdate))))

Comment: I really appreciate your help in solving this. Thanks you so much.

Comment: I hope you now understand why you need to provide better explanation and examples when you write questions. Both versions of my answer give the same results with the data you posted.